# Keeping track of when Python modules are imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

Does the interpreter somehow keep a timestamp of when a module is imported? Or is there an easy way of hooking into the import machinery to do this?

The scenario is a long-running Python process that at various points imports user-provided modules. I would like the process to be able to check "should I restart to load the latest code changes?" by checking the module file's timestamps against the time the module was imported.

Comment: you could increment the module version number at each change and then check the version numbers, e.g. `foo.__version__`?

Comment: For modules you have control over — which sounds like it's the case here — couldn't you just have some kind of version attribute into them and check that?

Comment: @martineau "When a module (or package) includes a version number, the version SHOULD be available in the `__version__` attribute." https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to automatically have an attribute (named `_loadtime` in the example code below) added to modules when they're imported. The code is based on Recipe 10.12 titled "Patching Modules on Import" in the book *Python Cookbook*, by David Beazley and Brian Jones, O'Reilly, 2013, which shows a technique that I adapted to do what you want.

For testing purposes I created this trivial `target_module.py` file:

```
print('in target_module')
```

Here's the example code:

```
import importlib
import sys
import time


class PostImportFinder:
    def __init__(self):
        self._skip = set()  # To prevent recursion.

    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        if fullname in self._skip:  # Prevent recursion
            return None
        self._skip.add(fullname)
        return PostImportLoader(self)


class PostImportLoader:
    def __init__(self, finder):
        self._finder = finder

    def load_module(self, fullname):
        importlib.import_module(fullname)
        module = sys.modules[fullname]

        # Add a custom attribute to the module object.
        module._loadtime = time.time()

        self._finder._skip.remove(fullname)
        return module


sys.meta_path.insert(0, PostImportFinder())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import time

    try:
        print('importing target_module')
        import target_module
    except Exception as e:
        print('Import failed:', e)
        raise

    loadtime = time.localtime(target_module._loadtime)
    print('module loadtime: {} ({})'.format(
            target_module._loadtime,
            time.strftime('%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S', loadtime)))
```

Sample output:

```
importing target_module
in target_module
module loadtime: 1604683023.2491636 (2020-Nov-06 09:17:03)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to get around how hacky this is, but how about something like this every time you import? (I don't know exactly how you're importing):

```
import time
from types import ModuleType

# create a dictionary to keep track
# filter globals to exclude things that aren't modules and aren't builtins 
MODULE_TIMES = {k:None for k,v in globals().items() if not k.startswith("__") and not k.endswith("__") and type(v) == ModuleType}


for module_name in user_module_list:
    MODULE_TIMES[module_name] = time.time()
    eval("import {0}".format(module_name))
```

And then you can reference this dictionary in a similar way later.